# TileMill: How to access geojson properties with CartoCSS

Tags: geojson, tilemill, cartocss

When trying to display a geojson layer in TileMill, is it possible to access the 'properties' of each feature?

My geojson looks like this:

```
        "type": "Feature", 
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point", 
            "coordinates": [2.22614, 48.8765]
            }, 
        "properties": {
            "type": "stop",
            "name": "SOME_NAME",
            "color": "#ff0000"
            }
```

and I would like to display the name in properties/name, using the color in properties/color.

Is it possible? Properties are clearly accessible since one can write this and it works:

```
#id[type='stop'] {
  /* various css rules */
  }
```

But is it possible to use properties in the css rules themselves? This for instance does not work:

```
#id[type='stop'] {
  marker-line-color: [color];
  }
```

(or any variation with or without quotes inside or outside brackets for 'color').

If it's not possible, in what other format should I transform the geojson in order to access properties of each element from the css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data properties can be used for filters in selectors (ie the `#id[type='stop']` part), but TileMill cannot currently assign colors or most other property types based on values in the data.

Instead, you would have to create a filter to check the data, then assign the color manually:

```
#id[type='stop'] {
  [color='#ff0000'] { marker-line-color: #ff0000; }
  [color='#00ff00'] { marker-line-color: #00ff00; }
  // etc.
}
```

This is a limitation of Mapnik, the rendering engine behind TileMill. Support for assigning more values based on the data is [a planned feature](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/issues/828), but not yet available.

Currently the only style properties that can accept data values are:

- `marker-width`
- `marker-height`
- `text-orientation`
- `building-height`
- `shield-name`
- `text-name`
- `marker-file` (within the URI)
- `shield-file` (within the URI)
- `point-file` (within the URI)

Since `marker-file` is supported, another option you have is creating a bunch of different SVG icons containing the appropriate color code in their name (eg `stop-#ff0000.svg`). Then you could have a style like this:

```
#id[type='stop'] {
  marker-file: url("icons/stop-[color].svg");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had finally figured out after some testing that it didn't have anything to do with geojson; you can indeed read and assign values to text-name but not to color. Cool to know it's a planned feature (sad to know it's already been two years...)

Comment: I was not able to get the attribute-based marker-file path to work. I tried double quotes, single quotes, and no quotes, but couldn't get it. I pasted the whole path instead to make sure I had it right, and I did because it worked fine. Also tried it nested, not nested, and without attributes, but still no soup. Kept getting an "unable to download" 403 error in CartoDB. Any ideas??